# Term for a feature that is always 0 in the training data

Tags: terminology

Is there any term to designate a feature that is always 0 in the training data? (1) calls it *unsupported features* but I wonder whether there exists any more commonly used term.

---

(1) Sutton, Charles, and Andrew McCallum. "[An introduction to conditional random fields](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/csutton/publications/crftut-fnt.pdf)." Machine Learning 4.4 (2011): 267-373.

Comment: You could call it a "constant feature" (though all 0 may be a special case of constant features)

Comment: @Zach Thanks,  wouldn't that imply that the feature is also constant in test set?

Comment: Very good point.  I don't know of an elegant term for that.  Here's what comes to mind: "train set constant" (a mouthful) or "uninformative features" (rather ambiguous).  Maybe also "zero variance" or "train set zero variance?"

Comment: I guess this requires some qualifications. Does it end up being constant due to resampling? Because, if you are doing holdout validation and a feature is constant, I wouldn't call it a feature, since it can't be related to any target within-sample